# Issue with SQL queries and Series / Type

Tags: f#, deedle

Here is my code to request a DateTime*float from my SQL DB
(I use : open FSharp.Data.TypeProviders)

```
    type FxTS = Series<DateTime,float>

    let get (req: RFxTS) =
        query { for d in db.Data_FXBFIX do
                where (d.Fxpair = (req.FxPair.ToString())
                    && (d.DatetimeUTC.Date >= req.Period.startDate)
                    && (d.DatetimeUTC.Date <= req.Period.endDate))
                sortBy d.DatetimeUTC
                select (d.DatetimeUTC, d.Value) }
        |> Series.ofObservations
        |> FxTS
```

And I get an error under FxTS: (when if I remove FxTS, I can see that this function returns indeed a Series

```
Type constraint mismatch. The type 
    'Series<DateTime,float>'    
is not compatible with type
    'seq<Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<DateTime,float>>'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would like to add to @zyzhu's answer is that

```
|> FxTS
```

is redundant. Basically, you can just get away with the explicit type annotation

```
let get (req: RFxTS) : FxTS =
        query { for d in db.Data_FXBFIX do
                where (d.Fxpair = (req.FxPair.ToString())
                    && (d.DatetimeUTC.Date >= req.Period.startDate)
                    && (d.DatetimeUTC.Date <= req.Period.endDate))
                sortBy d.DatetimeUTC
                select (d.DatetimeUTC, d.Value) }
        |> Series.ofObservations
```

as soon as `FxTS` is just a type alias for `Series<DateTime,float>` compiler expects it to have same constructors as `Series` and one of them is indeed `seq<Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<DateTime,float>>`

Comment: Thanks, I like this approach as it is the easier but I am still a bit confused why it works though.

Answer (score 2):

`Series.ofObservation` works with tuple sequence, not KeyValuePair. Just convert it to tuples before you run Series.ofObservations. See below a sample.

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open Deedle
let pairs = 
  [
    KeyValuePair(DateTime(2018,1,31),1.)
    KeyValuePair(DateTime(2018,2,28),2.)
  ]

pairs
|> Seq.map(fun x -> x.Key, x.Value)
|> Series.ofObservations
```